# How to rename all nodes in a graph?

Tags: python, networkx

I am using NetworkX to read a GraphML file. There are more than 1000 nodes in my GraphML graph and I am trying to change the ID of every node based on some conditions such as:

```
if "gold" in node.id: 
    node.id = "hello_world"
```

this is a sample of my input graph:

**graph.graphml**

```
<node id="gold_core.pc_loc_country_mapping"> 
  <data key="d0">pc_loc_country_mapping</data>
  <data key="d1">gold</data>
  <data key="d2">core</data>
</node>
<node id="gold_core.products">
  <data key="d0">products</data>
  <data key="d1">gold</data>
  <data key="d2">core</data>
</node>
```

**read_graph.py**

```
networkx_graph = nx.read_graphml(GRAPH_ML_PATH)    
nodes_to_remove = []
    for node, data in networkx_graph.nodes(data=True):
        if data['zone'] != GOLD_NODES_ID and networkx_graph.degree(node) < 1:
            nodes_to_remove.append(node)
    networkx_graph.remove_nodes_from(nodes_to_remove)
    return networkx_graph
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change the node ids, you can use the function [`relabel_nodes`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.relabel.relabel_nodes.html):

```
renaming_mapping = {}
for node, data in graph.nodes(data=True):
    if condition: 
        renaming_mapping[node] = "new individual name"
graph_with_new_names = nx.relabel_nodes(graph, renaming_mapping)
```